# Config NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate

I use config file for NHibernate . 
I want define more than one session-factrory in same config file . 
I do it like this : 
`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
<configSections>
<section name="hibernate-configuration"
 type="NHibernate.Cfg.ConfigurationSectionHandler, NHibernate" />
<section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,log4net" />
</configSections>
<hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
<session-factory name="test1">
  all properties
</session-factory>
  <session-factory name="test2">
  all properties
</session-factory>'
```

The application throw exception : 
nhibernate.cfg.HibernateConfigException : An exception occurred parsing configuration : The element 'hibernate-configuration' has invalid child element   'session-factory'

Answer (score 3):

You can't define two session factories in a single config file (the schema does not allow it, and NHibernate doesn't provide a way to access them anyway)

Use separate files or, better yet, one of the code-based approaches, which are more flexible.

See http://fabiomaulo.blogspot.com/2009/07/nhibernate-fluent-configuration.html and http://fabiomaulo.blogspot.com/2009/07/nhibernate-configuration-through.html